# Edit XML Layouts Before Inflating Them

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I need to make changes to an XML layout file before I inflate it, but any change I try to make give a `null object error`. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: you can not edit layout before inflating

Comment: `Is there any possible way to do this?` **NO**.

Comment: As above...you can't edit xml files directly in the running program. You can modify view and viewgroup values however. If you plan on creating dynamic views, create placeholder views in the xml for them. Or look into animation if you are planning on that,

Answer (score 1):

> I need to make changes to an XML layout file before I inflate it,

Then you need to modify your XML in your IDE. If you really mean "I need to make changes to the inflated objects before I inflate them", that is not possible, as time does not flow backwards in our portion of the universe.

Comment: So you can't inflate the layout in the background or make it hidden somehow while the changes are made?

Comment: @Axonshi123: I am not certain why you think that you need this. However, you are welcome to manually inflate the layout, using `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.whatever, theEventualParent, false)`. Then, make your changes to the contents, by calling `findViewById()` on the object returned from `inflate()` to get at the widgets inside the inflated layout. When ready, call `addView()` on `theEventualParent` (the container for these widgets) to attach them to the container for display.

Comment: You can set all the Views to be invisible inside the xml, change them after loading the content View and then make them visible. But... what for?

Comment: @CommonsWare Will try that. Thanks